Karhunen-Loeve expansion of a random variable in finite dimension
I found the Karhunen-Loeve expansion theorem here Karhunen-Loeve expansion . It seems to concern centered stochastic process in $L^2([0,1])$. I would like to know if I can use it for random vectors in $\mathbb{R^d}$
For exemple if I would like to replace $X_t$ with a random vector $Y$ that does not change with the variable $t$, and the $e_k$ with an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Thanks in advance.
